# How would you separate a list into sublists of all the duplicates in the original?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l = [a, a, a, b, b, c]

desired1 = [a, a, a]

desired2 = [b, b]

desired3 = [c]
```

desired could also be a list of all the lists above.

Comment: Are duplicates always grouped internally?

Comment: Hmm, they could be but it would be better if they could be out of order. Is it significantly easier if they are grouped internally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group common elements together:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
>>> 
>>> runs = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(l)]
>>> runs
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c']]
>>>
```

Note this will only work if the list has already been sorted, so you may have to sort before grouping:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] # unsorted
>>> runs = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(l))]
>>> runs
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c']]
>>>
```

Comment: Only works if sorted... well, if they are already grouped internally...

Comment: Yes I know. I guess I should mention that though.

Comment: Note that the complexity of this solution is O(N*LOG(N))

Answer (score 2):

Another option using **Counter** :)

```
from collections import Counter
l = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
c = Counter(l)
result = [ [k]*v for k, v in c.items() ]
```

Answer (score 1):

an easy way is to use a `dict`

```
dict = {}
for thing in list:
  dict[thing] += 1

list = []
for key in dict:
  curr_list = [] 
  for i in range(dict[key]):
    curr_list.append(key)
  list.append(curr_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly more straightforward `dict` approach

```
>>> l = [1,2,1,3,4,2,3,1,1,4]
>>> out = {}
>>> for i in set(l):
         out[i] = []
...
>>> for i in l:
...      out[i].append(i)
>>> out
{1: [1, 1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4, 4]}
>>> out.values()
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]
```